# Self-documenting WebAPI 2

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5.1 WebAPI 2 with attribute routing project I would like to document. The idea is to add a "describe" path/controller to each API that would create a list of "description" objects.

To make this useful, I would also like to force XML and reference an XML style sheet in the document to display the data.

How do I embed an XML style sheet with a WebAPI?

Comment: Your question doesn't contain a question. Have you tried the `Help` area that gets created when you add the WebAPI NuGet package?

Comment: I've re-worded to include a question.

Comment: You don't want to reinvent the wheel. Did you try the `/Help` page?

Comment: I didn't know there was one. I've been using the empty MVC project scaffold. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [swagger](http://swagger.io/)

It's a great tool to document and test the WebApi and you can also customize the UI.